# How are gigantic primes actually defined in the 1992 article by Samuel Yates?

Tags: number-theory, math-history

[*The Prime Glossary*](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=GiganticPrime) states:

> In a 1992 article, Samuel Yates coined the name **gigantic prime** for any prime with 10,000 or more decimal digits (he had also coined the term titanic primes a decade earlier).

But the [annotation](http://primes.utm.edu/references/refs.cgi?long=Yates92b) suggests that they were defined as primes with *over* rather than *at least* 10,000 digits:

> Here Yates defines primes with more than 10,000 digits to be gigantic primes. Actually Yates suggested this as a name for those with over 5,000 digits; but the list was growing so fast that when the editor asked me to revise this article after Yates death I changed it to 10,000.

Can anybody say whether primes with exactly 10,000 digits are gigantic according to the original article?

> **S. Yates**, "Collecting gigantic and titanic primes," *J. Recreational Math.*, **24**:3 (1992) 193--201.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigantic_prime), the first statement is true, i.e., "A gigantic prime is a prime number with at least 10,000 decimal digits."

Comment: Yes, and that is how it is commonly defined today, but that may be due to a false statement in _The Prime Glossary_. It would be interesting to know what the article where the term was coined actually says.

Answer (score 2):

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigantic_prime) page gives the following definition: A *gigantic prime* is a prime number with at least 10,000 decimal digits. It seems that the other statement in the prime glossary, namely "more than $10000$ digits" is wrong, as we know that the smallest gigantic prime is given by
$$
p=10^{9999}+33603,
$$
which has **exactly** $10000$ digits. Of course, a final proof, that this is what Yates has written, can only be obtained by consulting his article (which can be ordered in a university library).

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem that the Wikipedians used the original article as a source. The statement that $10^{9999}+33603$ is the smallest gigantic prime conforms with the today's definition but that does not mean that it conforms with the original one. I am fine with using _gigantic prime_ in the sense given by Wikipedia, so my question is of solely historic interest.

Comment: Indeed, Paulo Ribenboim states in _The New Book of Prime Number Records_: “In his 1992 paper, Yates introduced the “gigantic primes,” which are those having more than 10000 decimal digits. […] Caldwell informed me of the number of known large primes: 10170 titanic primes; of these 500 with more than 5000 digits and 78 with more than 10000 digits (gigantic primes).”

So was he misled by the annotation as well? Made the error independently?

Though _The Little Book of Bigger Primes_ says: “In 1992, Yates called _gigantic_ all primes with at least 10000 digits.”

Comment: It seems that now all definitions of primes by size (titanic, gigantic,mega, etc) are using "at least $n$ digits", and not "more than $n$ digits". But again, all depends on what you want to know, and it seems you must  get hold of Yates article. If you are really interested in the history of primes, this is a *must* for you. I would not depend on any answers on MSE here, but look for myself.

Comment: Also [confusing](https://books.google.com/books?id=w-_xAAAAMAAJ&q="sinkers+of+the+titanics+are+those"): “(The sinkers of the titanics are those people who discover primes with more than 1000 digits).” Note that _The Prime Glossary_ states: “He also called those who proved their primality **titans**.”

Comment: Perhaps he used both terms, then. (Maybe the difference is that a (1) titan is everyone who once discovered a titanic prime while a (2) sinker of the titanics is one who regularly does so. Or (2) includes those who discovered a titanic prime without proving its primality.) The reason I asked is that it is not easy to get this article (maybe someone here actually has it); it cannot be accessed at JSTOR etc. WorldCat lists two Danish libraries while I live in Germany and it is not clear whether one of them has the right issue.